# Zookeeper connection in java

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

The below code(not mine) is supposed to check the connection status of a zookeeper by using the znode_exists() method. I want to use it at a producerAPI before a message publish. But i am getting an error at defining the ZooKeeperConnection object. I have added the possible classes and libraries.

```
import java.io.IOException;
//import org.apache.zookeeper.*; adding this doesn't help
import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain;
import org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException;
import org.apache.zookeeper.WatchedEvent;
import org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher;
import org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher.Event.KeeperState;
import org.apache.zookeeper.data.Stat;
public class ZKExists {
    private static ZooKeeper zk;
       private static ZooKeeperConnection conn; // Object cannot be resolve to a type

       // Method to check existence of znode and its status, if znode is available.
       public static Stat znode_exists(String path) throws
          KeeperException,InterruptedException {
          return zk.exists(path, true);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,KeeperException {
          String path = "/Znode_path"; // Assign znode to the specified path

          try {
              ZooKeeperConnection conn = new ZooKeeperConnection();
             zk = conn.connect("localhost");
             Stat stat = znode_exists(path); // Stat checks the path of the znode

             if(stat != null) {
                System.out.println("Node exists and the node version is " +
                stat.getVersion());
             } else {
                System.out.println("Node does not exists");
             }

          } catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // Catches error messages
          }
       }

}
```

Which library am i missing to make the object valid ?

Comment: Do you intend to publish the message to a an Apache Kafka topic?

Comment: Assuming you do: You shouldn't need to check Zookeeper before publishing, just publish to Kafka and handle any errors. Kafka requires Zookeeper running anyway, otherwise it won't work. In production you would monitor the apps.

Comment: @JensHoffmann Yes I do. I just thought it would be better to have a check if any brokers are available. I do understand a broker check would be more sensible than zk check. But I am not able to use "zkUtils.getAllBrokersInCluster()" as a list<brokers>.